# Not sure how to use malloc() and free() properly

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, free

```
int listLength(struct node *r) { 

    int *len = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(!r) { 
       free(len);
       return *len; 
    }

    while(r) { 
         r = r->next; 
           *len += 1; 
    }
    free(len)
    return *len; 
}
```

I wrote this function to calculate the length of the linked list. I am still learning pointers by playing with them. I understand I could have used a simple len variable in the function,but I want to learn the basics of dynamic memory allocation. Why the length is always 0 after even though list has few elements? When should `free()` be called ?

Comment: You can’t free the memory and then use it. You could store it in a temporary variable, use free, and then return that. `int t = *len; free(len); return t;`

Comment: 1). you don't initialize len with 0. 2) you access the free'ed memorry.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever for dynamic allocation in this function *at all*. Just declare a local `int len = 0;` accumulate your count, then `return len;`

Comment: Before `free(len)`, you need to store the value pointed by `len` in some other variable. For example: `int len2 = *len`. This essentially takes out the whole point in the dynamic allocation of `len` to begin with, and you may as well just allocate it statically (i.e. `int len`). In general, you need to use dynamic memory allocation when the amount of memory required is known only during runtime. In the given example, the amount of memory required - `sizeof(int)` - is well known (constant and fixed) **before** runtime.

Comment: Also, you should check malloc returned value before accessing the memory. 'if (!len) return -1;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the memory once you `free()` it. So,

```
   free(len);
   return *len;
```

is wrong and undefined behavior.

Instead, you can use a local variable to hold the *value* and `return` it.

Also, FWIW,

```
int *len = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(!r) { 
       free(len);
       return *len; 
    }
```

in the above code, you're trying to use the `*len` as return value, which is *uninitialized*. Even without the `free()`ing, you should not do that.

Also, you should always check for the success of `malloc()` vefore using the returned pointer.

A modified version:

```
int listLength(struct node *r) { 

    int *lenp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int len = 0;

    if (!lenp)     //check malloc success
        exit(-1);    


    *lenp = len;

    if(!r) { 
       free(lenp);
       return len; 
    }

    while(r) { 
         r = r->next; 
           *lenp += 1; 
    }

    len = *lenp;
    free(lenp);
    return len; 
}
```

---

EDIT:

In your case, there is no need to use dynamic memory allocation at all. AS suggested by Mr. **@ Barak Manos** and Mr. **@ WhozCraig**, you should use dynamic memory allocation only when the memory requirement is not known at compile time. Otherwise, in general, static (compile time) memory allocation should do just fine.

A better and cleaner approach to your code,

```
int listLength(struct node *r) { 

    int len = 0;

    while(r) { 
         r = r->next; 
           len += 1; 
    }
    return len; 
}
```

Comment: You addressed only the coding error, and not the (more general) question given at the title - when to call `malloc`. You might want to mention that dynamic memory allocation is needed when the exact amount of memory required is known **only** during runtime, and that static memory allocation should generally be used in all other cases.

Comment: @barakmanos I think the title is misleading, please see the last line of the question body. :-)

Comment: @barakmanos OP wants to leran about pointers. However, in regards to your really helpful comment, I've updated my answer. Please review. :-)

Comment: Done, +1....... BTW, in the last code example, there is really no need for that `if` statement (will return 0 without it).

Answer (score 0):

In general: after you have `free()`'d a memory block, you must *never* access it anymore. Just think of have given that block away. It is not yours anymore!

From this follow that you have to free a block only if you don't want to access it anymore. That's a **fundamental** rule; never ever break it.

For this example, as others have stated, there is actually no need to use dynamic memory at all.

Oh, and: you really should never cast the result of malloc! It returns `void *` wich can be assigned to any other pointer type. Read the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.5.16.1 .